# How to sync Calendar Event across multiple users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

How can I sync the events between multiple users using Microsoft Graph,
For example, if both user A and B is in the same Event, and one of them update the event then both the events in user's A and B should change too.

Can I do this using iCalUId ?

Comment: If your events are in different calendars they will have different id’s

Answer (score 0):

many customers use Modern Group calendars to achieve this. And one user authors the calendar and members of the group see these event show up in it. This obviously depends on A and B making sense to be in a group for this.